# How to append a result of a command to a logfile name in CMD?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am querying a count of pages in the document and outputting to the log file. However, i actually would want the count of pages in the log file name.
Here is a made-up example is:

> "made up command - get count of pages in the doc" > logfile_+<53>+_pages.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Might be clunky, but works.

> "c:\program files (x86)\gs\gs8.70\bin\gswin32c" -q  -dNoDisplay -c "(u:/path/121803.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit" > b:\121803.txt
>
> set /p myvar=b:\121803page%myvar%.txt
>   the output is 121803page94.txt

Comment: Please improve the formatting of your code (line breaks for example)

Comment: the only thing, I could not figure out is running in a batch mode. for some reason with Setlocal EnableDelayedExpressions my set /p mvar is not recognized. Even after setting my var as !myvar! in the filename.  Any ideas? Also, i i am running multiple rows of the example above and noticing that a previous myvar result is carrying into a next row so my filename shows a page number from the text file read into previous myvar variable.